# .filter() is not removing complex data types i.e. 0 & {}

Tags: javascript

This function is removing those which are `falsey` however are not removing the empty Object or the 0. Why?

```js
function removeBlank(array) {
  return array.filter(Boolean);
}
console.log(removeBlank([0, false, [], undefined, {}, NaN, 'Kevin']));
```

Comment: An empty object does not evaluate to a falsey value in Javascript.

Comment: Zero gets removed, check your output.

Comment: [Truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) <-> [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)